# time condition for revicer for GCM purpose

Tags: android, android-studio, google-cloud-messaging

I started to use gcm -Google Cloud Messaging and it work very well.
my app ask from google id and send it to my server
and my server use this ID to send to app messages - this works very well.

now i need to make my app to delay/stop receiving messages for the night hours(22:00-07:00)
(unless the user uses the app in night).

dose has a way to prevent recivieng messages in night hours and receiving
all of the messages that sent over night in 07:00AM??

what are my options?

i noticed to unregister() function
when i am getting message in 01:00AM
i can check the time condition and check app activity flag
and call unregister() function
whitout show Notification on screen and play sound...

but this single message that triger the unregister() function will wasted
and i dont know how to make register()  again

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution is to not show message in that period.

```
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
         Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
         if(c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)>22 || c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)<7) break;
    }
```

Comment: i already thought about it and i try to avoid losing night notification
i looking for away to make delay in receiving and show them on morning(07:00).